# Changing an ID name by location in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, data-cleaning

I have 2 repeated IDs in my data frame, and I want to change the name of one.

When I use revalue function by dplyr, the new name is assigned to both.

That's why I wanted to do it by specifying the location of the ID by column and row and then changing it but I couldn't find how to do it.

**In short, my question is how can I change only one ID(element)'s name if it is repeated twice in a data frame?**

*Edit:* To be more specific let's say my data is this-

```
Value <- c(12,23,4,5)
ID <- c("A", "B", "A", "C")
Score1 <- c(3, 2, 1, 4)
Score2 <- c(4,5,9,10)
mydf <- data.frame(Value, ID, Score1, Score2)
mydf
# Value ID Score1 Score2
1    12  A      3      4
2    23  B      2      5
3     4  A      1      9
4     5  C      4     10
```

I want to change the Second "A" to "A-1".

(It could be a very basic question, I am new in R, sorry :D)

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of this, it is very difficult to assist otherwise

Comment: Please show a little bit of sample data. 3 or 4 rows, 3 or 4 columns should be plenty, along with the expected output. If you have a sample data frame in R, you can create a copy/pasteable version with `dput()`, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:4, 1:3])` for the first 4 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: You may use `i1 <- df1$ID ==1 & !duplicated(df1$ID); df1$ID[i1] <- 'yourvalue'`

Comment: `mydf$ID <- make.unique(mydf$ID)`. If the `"A.1"` really needs to be `"A-1"`, then `mydf$ID <- sub(".", "-", make.unique(mydf$ID), fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @r2evans thank you! This is worked. I first used the "make.unique" function and then rechanged it with revalue function from dplyr to give the value that I want.

    Because A-1 was just an example, I actually wanted to give a totally different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would want subsequent `A`s (if then have more than one duplicate) to be sequentially numbered, then `make.unique` works well here:

```r
make.unique(mydf$ID)
# [1] "A"   "B"   "A.1" "C"
```

If you must have it with a dash instead of a period, then

```r
sub(".", "-", make.unique(mydf$ID), fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "A"   "B"   "A-1" "C"
```

Either way, this can be easily reassigned back into `mydf$ID`.